# Логика входа в систему в angularjs\asp.net приложении

Tags: angularjs, asp.net

Доброго времени суток,Стэковерфлоучане, пишу админку для своего приложения и зашел в тупик, вот есть форма для входа в панель администратора, я беру данные из формы, отправляю на сервер, там происходит проверка:

1. Если пароль и логин совпадают - возвращаю true
2. Если пароль и логин не совпадают - возвращаю false

В случае возврата False - все понятно, а как быть с true, что дальше делать ?

Заранее спасибо за Ваши ответы и подсказки !

Comment: Обычно после успешной проверки логина и пароля, информацию об этом сохраняют в *cookie*. А вообще, в **asp.net** есть встроенная авторизация.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko спасибо за ваш комментарий, я просто хотел своими руками написать и разобраться как это работает. А может вы знаете как прикрутить авторизацию если создавал пустой проект ?

Comment: Механизм везде стандартный, надо записать информацию о пользователе в сессию. Погуглите *asp.net forms authentication*. Можете посмотреть неплохую статью по теме [Реализация аутентификации с помощью форм](http://professorweb.ru/my/ASP_NET/security/level2/2_2.php)

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko супер, спасибо, можете скопипастить в ответ - отмечу как решённый .

Comment: К сожалению, ответы, которые содержат только ссылки тут не приветствуются. Что бы дать исчерпывающий ответ, надо привести пример работающего кода. Сделать это будет сложновато))

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko а мы никому не скажем) ну ок, спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Существует несколько способов авторизации в *asp.net*.

Способ с помощью *forms authentication*.

Для начала укажем, что мы будем использовать данный способ авторизации.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
 <forms name=".ASPXFORMSDEMO" loginUrl="logon.aspx" protection="All" path="/" timeout="30" />
</authentication>
```

Создадим страницу входа:

```
<h3>
<font face="Verdana">Logon Page</font>
</h3>
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>Email:</td>
  <td><input id="txtUserName" type="text" runat="server"></td>
  <td><ASP:RequiredFieldValidator ControlToValidate="txtUserName"
       Display="Static" ErrorMessage="*" runat="server" 
       ID="vUserName" /></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Password:</td>
  <td><input id="txtUserPass" type="password" runat="server"></td>
  <td><ASP:RequiredFieldValidator ControlToValidate="txtUserPass"
      Display="Static" ErrorMessage="*" runat="server" 
      ID="vUserPass" />
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Persistent Cookie:</td>
  <td><ASP:CheckBox id="chkPersistCookie" runat="server" autopostback="false" /></td>
  <td></td>
 </tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" Value="Logon" runat="server" ID="cmdLogin"><p></p>
<asp:Label id="lblMsg" ForeColor="red" Font-Name="Verdana" Font-Size="10" runat="server" />
```

Затем вешаем обработчик событий на **input**

```
private void cmdLogin_ServerClick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
 //Функция ValidateUser проверяет логин и пароль пользователя
 if (ValidateUser(txtUserName.Value,txtUserPass.Value) )
    //Здесь мы записываем данные пользователя в сессию
    FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(txtUserName.Value,chkPersistCookie.Checked);
 else
    Response.Redirect("logon.aspx", true);
}
```

Не забываем добавить пространство имен:

```
using System.Web.Security;
```

Для того, что бы разавторизовать пользователя надо выполнить:

```
 FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
```